# How to avoid using the word "corresponding" in a casual chat?

Tags: phrase-requests, distributive-determiners

For instance, I want to say this:

> If I connect hardware 1 and hardware 2, can I still access them separately through their corresponding network ports?

But the word *corresponding* seems too formal for my taste (not saying there is anything wrong with it). Is there a more casual way to form this question?

Comment: Is this an ELL question? Seems like a thesaurus could answer your question. Also omitting the word completely would work fine.

Comment: R Mac is right, but if you insist you could try associated / individual /  own

Comment: "Vocabulary" was definitely not the right tag for this question, so I edited it. I think that "phrase-requests" works best, but please change it if you can find a more appropriate one.

Comment: Why do you even need the word "corresponding"? It seems like you could just omit it entirely.

Comment: There's a lot of formal language in the sentence besides 'corresponding'. But I'm not sure what the 'correspondence' is to? Isn't ' ... can I still access them separately through their individual network ports' more accurate?

Answer (score 1):

> If I connect piece 1 and piece 2, can I still access each through its own network port?

How is this? I've removed as many words as possible while trying to keep the meaning clear. I don't think you need *separately*, but you can of course add it if you like.